# how to I get Instruction hex code in x86?

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, machine-code, self-modifying

```
section .data

section .text

global _start


_start:
    mov eax, loop ; eax <- addr of loop
    mov ebx, new
    mov ecx, new   
    mov esi, 2
loop:
    mov edx, [eax] ; edx <- instruction of loop, but not worked
    mov [ebx], edx 
    add eax, esi
    add ebx, esi
    cmp eax, ecx
    jne loop
    mov ecx, ebx
new:
```

[x86 code picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE1WA.png)

What I want in this code is to put the Instruction Hex code of the loop in edx.

If you see here, mov edx and [eax] are stored in the loop, and I think the instruction code is **0x1389108b**, but the actual saved value is **0x13cc10cc**. I don't know how to get this value **0x1389108b**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction at `loop` is 8b 10, and the next instruction is 89 13. However you have set a breakpoint at each of those instructions, so the debugger has overwritten the first byte of each instruction with a breakpoint instruction. The code for a breakpoint is cc, so that’s what your program reads. If you run it without setting breakpoints, you’ll get the value you expect.

Comment: GDB has an `hbreak` to use a HW-assisted break point (debug registers instead of `0xcc`) which could also avoid this.  I think there's a duplicate on SO of another question about loads seeing the `0xcc`...  Yeah, found one where Jester mentioned `hbreak` in an answer.  And turns out there are several Visual Studio debugger duplicates.